# Is using the $.ajax() function in phonegap possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

So, I created an app using jquery and what i did is I imported a function called $.ajax to accsess an api. But when I tested the app it did not work on my android phone, but on the pc it worked, so my question would be is using the $.ajax() function in phonegap possible?

Comment: yes it does work. is your phone wifi turned off? Also, is your $.ajax trying to invoke some webapi through a path that is relative to your development machine?

Comment: Sure your phone app has internet permission?

Comment: $.ajax() is a function to invoke async postback using jquery. It is independent on the platform and is supported by newer version of browsers. If you application supports html, it would work

Comment: Do you need to add the requested origin to your app's whitelist? What version of Cordova are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use whitelist plugin to successfully call apis. $.ajax() will start working, once you add whitelist plugin. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Add following line in config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to debug your app using chrome: [How to remote debug](http://www.adamwadeharris.com/remote-debugging-in-phonegap-with-chrome-devtools/).
This will help you a lot in debugging errors instead "guessing in the blind".

To answer your question. Yes, it is possible to use Ajax in phonegap.